# LINQ query to find related data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I got some help with my recursive product category tree view here on Stack Overflow before, and this is working:

Entity model:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentCategory))]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } //nav.prop to parent
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } //nav. prop to children

    public List<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var categories = _context.ProductCategories.Include(e => e.Children).ToList();
var topLevelCategories = categories.Where(e => e.ParentId == null);
return View(topLevelCategories);
```

View:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <li>
        @item.Title
        <ul>
            @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", item.Children)
        </ul>
    </li>
    }
}
```

But when I tried to translate this setup to my viewmodel (and adding a property for counting products in each category, as well as a list of products without any category connection) ...:

Viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public string ProductCountInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return Products != null && Products.Any() ? Products.Count().ToString() : "0";
        }
    }

    public ViewModelProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to parent
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProductCategory> Children { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to children
    public List<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; } // Products in this category
    public List<ViewModelProduct> OrphanProducts { get; set; } // Products with no reference in ProductInCategory
}
```

Controller:

```
            var VMCategories = _context.ProductCategories
                        .Include(e => e.Children)
                        .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
                        .Where(r => r.ParentId == null) // only need root level categories in the View
                        .Select(v => new ViewModelProductCategory
                        {
                            Id = v.Id,
                            ParentId = v.ParentId,
                            Title = v.Title,
                            SortOrder = v.SortOrder,
                            // get products without a category:
                            OrphanProducts = v.ProductInCategory
                                            .Where(o => !_context.ProductsInCategories.Any(pc => o.Id == pc.ProductId))
                                            .Select(orph => new ViewModelProduct
                                            {
                                                Id = orph.Product.Id,
                                                Title = orph.Product.Title,
                                                Price = orph.Product.Price,
                                                Info = orph.Product.Info,
                                                SortOrder = orph.SortOrder
                                            })
                                            .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
                                            .ToList()

                        })
                        .ToList();
        return View(VMCategories);
```

View:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <li>
        @item.Title (@item.ProductCountInfo)
        <ul>
            @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", item.Children)
        </ul>
    </li>
    }
}
```

... it won't work any more. The view does render, but it is just showing the root categories. It seems that my modified query won't get any of the children categories. When I inspect the query result, the Children property is null.

**EDIT**

I'm going with @Rainman's solution, and have changed my query `.Select` to include `Children = v.Children,`, and changing my viewmodel navigational properties thusly:

```
public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } //nav.prop to parent
public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } //nav. prop to children
```

I have also created the new viewmodel `CategoryRecursiveModel` and changed my view to this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>

<ul>
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @item.Title (@item.ProductCountInfo)
            <ul>
                @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", new CategoryRecursiveModel
                {
                    Children = item.Children.ToList();
                })
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

Now I'm faced with InvalidOperationException, as the view is expecting an IEnumerable of ViewModelProductCategory, but receives CategoryRecursiveModel.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework Core or Entity Framework 6?

Comment: Entity Framework Core

Comment: You seem to be missing the fact that `ToList` call here `var categories = _context.ProductCategories.Include(e => e.Children).ToList();` is crucial for your original solution, since it's forcing EF to load the whole tree in memory and also do the heavy work of connecting navigation properties (the so called navigation property fixup) for you. Once you start using projection, you have to do all that `Parent` / `Children` property filling yourself.

Comment: Although the question marked as duplicate is for EF6, the same principle and solution applies to EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not selecting the `Children` for second query;

```
var VMCategories = _context.ProductCategories
    .Include(e => e.Children)
    .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
    .Where(r => r.ParentId == null) // only need root level categories in the View
    .Select(v => new ViewModelProductCategory
    {
        Id = v.Id,
        Children = v.Children, // Select it
        ParentId = v.ParentId,
        Title = v.Title,
        SortOrder = v.SortOrder,
        // get products without a category:
        OrphanProducts = v.ProductInCategory
            .Where(o => !_context.ProductsInCategories.Any(pc => o.Id == pc.ProductId))
            .Select(orph => new ViewModelProduct
            {
                Id = orph.Product.Id,
                Title = orph.Product.Title,
                Price = orph.Product.Price,
                Info = orph.Product.Info,
                SortOrder = orph.SortOrder
            })
            .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
            .ToList()

    })
    .ToList();
```

> ```
> public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } //nav.prop to parent
> public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } //nav. prop to children
> ```

Also, navigation properties exist only for EF entities not `ViewModelProductCategory` model class or other classes.

**EDIT**

Create a model class for `_CategoryRecursive` view;

```
public class CategoryRecursiveModel
{
    public List<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And the change the main view;

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @item.Title (@item.ProductCountInfo)
            <ul>
                @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", new CategoryRecursiveModel
                {
                    Children = item.Children.ToList();
                })
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to use my viewmodel in the view? When using the viewmodel after your changes, I get InvalidOperationException because the view is expecting my viewmodel, and your changes makes the model a System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[MyStore.Models.ProductCategory]. If I change the view to expect the entity model, my ProductCountInfo and OrphanProducts properties are lost. And aren't there some security issues when using entity models in views?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I get InvalidOperationException because the view is expecting my viewmodel, but receives the CategoryRecursiveModel.