# Converting from using entity model to using viewmodel

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

When I use this query and entity model, things are working:

```
var categories = _context.ProductCategories.Include(e => e.Children).ToList();
var topLevelCategories = categories.Where(e => e.ParentId == null);
return View(topLevelCategories);
```

The entity model:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentCategory))]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } //nav.prop to parent
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } //nav. prop to children

    public List<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
}
```

... but when I try to switch to using a viewmodel instead, I get this error message:

"InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[MyStore.Models.ProductCategory]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory]'."

I understand that the model being sent to the view is not right, but I don't understand why.

My viewmodel query:

```
var VMCategories = _context.ProductCategories
                .Include(e => e.Children).ToList()
                .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
                .Where(r => r.ParentId == null)
                    .Select(v => new ViewModelProductCategory
                    {
                        Id = v.Id,
                        Children = v.Children,
                        ParentId = v.ParentId,
                        Title = v.Title,
                        SortOrder = v.SortOrder
                    })
                    .ToList();
return View(VMCategories);
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public string ProductCountInfo =>
        Products != null && Products.Any() ? Products.Count().ToString() : "0";

    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to parent
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to children

    public List<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; } // Products in this category
    public List<ViewModelProduct> OrphanProducts { get; set; } // Products with no references in ProductInCategory

}
```

The Index-view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>

<ul>
    @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive", Model)
</ul>
```

_CategoryRecursive.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>

<ul style="list-style:none;padding-left:0px;">
   @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.Children != null)
            {
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", item.Children)
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Where is/are my mistake/s?

Comment: "I can't get it to work:" is not a problem statement. What exact issue are you getting?

Comment: Research the exception, add `.ToList()`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Please see update.

Comment: What is the model type declared at the top of the view?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>

Comment: Children property of `ViewModelProductCategory` class is still of type `public IEnumerable<ProductCategory>` that's why you get error while you render partial view `_CategoryRecursive.cshtml` in itself. You need to change the Children property to `IEnumerable<ViewModelProductCategory>` and populate it properly.

Comment: I think all your recent problems started with taking a wrong advice(answer) to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077945/linq-query-to-find-related-data). The original ViewModel is correct, you just need to find a way to populate it correctly as pointed out by @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 1):

Your view model is a mix and match of entity model and view models. For example the view model Children collection is of type entity model while it should be a collection of view models as well. Keep it clean and don't let your entity models leak into your view models

```
public class ProductCategoryVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategoryVM> Children { get; set; }
}
```

once you have that in place

- fetch all categories entity models
- counting the products as well
- map them to categories view models

(knowing that there are multiple levels of categories)

```
var query = from category in context.Categories
            let products = from product in context.Products
                            where product.CategoryId == category.Id
                            select product
            select new ProductCategoryVM
            {
                Id = category.Id,
                ParentId = category.ParentId,
                Title = category.Title,
                Products = products.Count(),
                ...
            };
var viewmodels = query.ToList();
```

Next step could be to recursively attach children to corresponding parents starting with root. (Check [gist](https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/aa572e1d91bf724ed1811390dc06fa8d#file-stack-48206797-cs) for the whole picture)

```
var root = viewmodels
    .Where(p => p.ParentId == null)
    .FirstOrDefault();
root.Traverse(viewmodels);

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Traverse(this ProductCategoryVM node, IEnumerable<ProductCategoryVM> nodes)
    {
        var children = nodes.Where(p => p.ParentId == node.Id);
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            child.Traverse(nodes);
        }

        node.Children = children;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Will your query work when children have children as well?
2. What about my ProductCountInfo-property from my viewmodel? I need the number of products in each category. If I can't (or shouldn't) have a reference to the entity model in the viewmodel, how could I get that number?

Comment: 1. The update highlights the approach for supporting as many levels as needed by retrieving categories with one query to the database and grouping the children using recursion

Comment: 2. Decorate your view model with any fields relevant for the outcome, just make sure you don't reference entity models in them. For product count, just compute the number at query time and map it to a counter/producs field in the view model